# How do I select only some values in the column using pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a pivot table, which will sort the column values and show the data.

I cannot able to select values in the columns

for example:

```
df = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")
```

inside this file

```
column name 1: cars : nissan, honda, hyundai, toyota, benz
column name 2: color: white, yellow, red, black, blue
column name 3: year: 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016
```

I want to make a pivot table as follows:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['cars','color'], values='year', aggfunc='count', margins=True)
```

I want to create a pivot table which shows only nissan & honda in the cars column, and only white & black in the color column.

Comment: Why not filter or query only the data you want to show, then creat the pivot from that? `df1=df[(df['color'].isin(colorsyouwant))&(df['cars'].isin(carsyouwant)]; df1.pivot(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) your pivoted table based on those values:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['cars','color'], values='year', aggfunc='count', margins=True)
pivoted_df.loc[(['honda', 'nissan'], ['white', 'black']), :]
```